# ServiceStack Rest - Complex uri hierarchies

Tags: c#, rest, servicestack

I'm creating a rest webservice using the c# framework 'servicestack' (http://www.servicestack.net/) and I'm having issues trying to figure out how to support more complex rest hierarchies

And I'm configuring various routes and it works perfectly

```
Routes
    .Add<MerchantDto>("/merchants")
    .Add<MerchantDto>("/merchants/{id}")
    .Add<MerchantDto>("/merchantGroups/{merchantGroupId}/merchants")
    .Add<MerchantDto>("/merchantGroups/{merchantGroupId}/merchants/{id}")

    .Add<StoreDto>("/stores")
    .Add<StoreDto>("/stores/{id}")
    .Add<StoreDto>("/merchants/{merchantId}/stores")
    .Add<StoreDto>("/merchants/{merchantId}/stores/{id}");
```

This all works fine. This problem is doing this....

```
    .Add<StoreDto>("/merchantGroups/{merchantGroupId}/merchants/{merchantId}/stores/{id}
```

The problem here is that the StoreDto object only contains a MerchantId, it does not contain a MerchantGroupId so this wouldn't work.

One solution would be to add the MerchantGroupId to the DTO but the problem is that I am sharing the DTO with some other WCF services and it might be confusing if I were have a MerchantGroupId property in the StoreDto which is never populated during a retrieval operation.

Plus I see this as cropping up at different places so I was hoping there was a better way to do it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why would you want to use a Url containing information the client doesn't have? It's unclear what your objectives are here.

Comment: I was thinking it would be better if the entire thing go sorta, flowed all the way? So you get the merchant via the /merchantGroups/merchant url and continue on that 'url path' to get the store.

Comment: Well the client can't make it up, you either have to give it the merchengGroupId or you give it the Url it should post to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @myth says I am just making things complicated by trying to generate MVC-like url paths.

I am sticking to using the uri paths as is.