# Complex routes in ServiceStack

Tags: c#, .net, api, servicestack

I'm trying to use ServiceStack to write a wrapper for BitBucket api. The api has quite complex urls, for example:

```
bitbucket.org/api/1.0/repositories/{accountname}/{repo_slug}/issues/{issue_id}/
```

This route is for getting an issue from an id. The issue is a part of the repo_slug repository and that is part of the accountname user's repositores. These two parameters are not a part of the issue. So how do I go and write a route for this? I tried this:

```
[Route("/repositories/{Accountname}/{RepositorySlug}/issues/{local_id}")]
public class GetIssue : IReturn<Issue>{
        public string AccountName { get; set; }
        public string RepositorySlug { get; set; }

        // issue object properties from here on
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string priority { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public User reported_by { get; set; }
        public string utc_last_updated { get; set; }
        public int comment_count { get; set; }
        public Metadata metadata { get; set; }
        public string content { get; set; }
        public string created_on { get; set; }
        public int local_id { get; set; }
        public int follower_count { get; set; }
        public string utc_created_on { get; set; }
        public string resource_uri { get; set; }
        public bool is_spam { get; set; }
}
```

So basically I combined the two parameters together with the whole Issue DTO. This works for GET request but when I try to PUT the updated Issue then I get an error from bitbucket.

So then I went ahead and tried to fake the paths that are called:

```
[Route("/repositories/a/a/issues/{Id}")]
public class GetIssue : IReturn<Issue>{
        public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I'm just using ID here, for brevity, but here it would be the whole DTO. Then when I make the request I fake the url that I get from the route like this:

```
public Issue GetIssue(int issueId){
   _url = "repositories/" + _accountName + "/" + _repository + "/issues/" + issueId;
   return _sharpBucket.Get(new GetIssue{ Id = issueId}, _url);
}
```

This is the get method that is called from above.

```
public T Get<T>(IReturn<T> request, string url = null){
            return Send(request, 
                        HttpMethods.Get, 
                         overrideUrl: url, 
                         sendRequestBody: false);
}
```

And the send that is called from above:

```
    private T Send<T>(IReturn<T> request, string method, string overrideUrl = null, bool sendRequestBody = true){
        var relativeUrl = overrideUrl ?? request.ToUrl(method);
        var body = sendRequestBody ? QueryStringSerializer.SerializeToString(request) 
                                   : null;

        var json = Send(relativeUrl, method, body);

        var response = json.FromJson<T>();
        return response;
    }

    public T Send<T>(IReturn<T> request){
        var method = request is IPost<T> ?
            HttpMethods.Post
            : request is IPut<T> ?
                HttpMethods.Put
                : request is IDelete<T> ?
                    HttpMethods.Delete :
                    HttpMethods.Get;

        return Send(request, method, sendRequestBody: false);
    }
```

This kinda works. Is there a better way? I guess I must be missing something. I saw a similar topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12510017/servicestack-rest-complex-uri-hierarchies), but it doesn't offer an solution.

**Update:**

Seems this is bugged in v3 versions. Sticking to my "faking" urls method. The culprit seems to be GetQueryProperties method of UrlExtensions class: http://www.diffchecker.com/u1nyqpcw

Answer (score 1):

The [Routing docs on the wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing) provide info on Routing in ServiceStack. Also what you're trying to do here is the same approach as [ServiceStack's Stripe Gateway](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Stripe) which uses attributed DTO's and a [generic StripeGateway client](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Stripe/blob/master/src/Stripe/StripeGateway.cs#L355) to provide a typed API client.

There are some issues with your routes which should start with a `/` and the components need to be seperated with slashes so:

```
[Route("repositories/{Accountname}/{RepositorySlug }issues/{local_id}")]
```

Should instead be:

```
[Route("/repositories/{Accountname}/{RepositorySlug}/issues/{local_id}")]
```

Another customization option useful for typed gateways like this is to use `[IgnoreDataMember]` to specify properties that should only be on the route and not in the POST'ed DTO, e.g:

```
[Route("/path/{UseOnlyOnUrl}")]
public class Request
{
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public string UseOnlyOnUrl { get; set; }

    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

A quick way to check check what urls the routes generate is to use the `To{Verb}Url()` extension methods, e.g:

```
new Request().ToGetUrl().Print();
new Request().ToPostUrl().Print();
new Request().ToPutUrl().Print();
new Request().ToDeleteUrl().Print();
new Request().ToUrl("CustomVerb","json").Print();
```

You can use these to verify what paths each Request DTO will generate when used in different HTTP Methods.

Comment: Yeah I had some typos with the routes, I have corrected them, thanks for noticing.
Seems that GetStripeCard route is similar to mine. I'll take a look at it in the morning and get back to you. I tried the [IgnoreDataMemeber] but then I got an exception from the ToUrl method if I remember correctly. Was this functionality improved after v4.0?

Comment: @MitjaBezenšek it would help if you can show the exception details as well as the expected vs actual output and the C# snippet used to generate the routes. As for v4, development started almost 1 year ago, a lot has improved since then.

Comment: I think I might have found the difference between my code and the stripe example. Seems like the ConfigScope does something similar to my hack, only that it uses the [IgnoreDataMemeber]values for constructing routes but ignores them when POSTing. Can you confirm this? When I removed it from the example I got an error from Stripe saying that it received unknown parameters. Ill play with it tomorrow, now I'm too tired :)

Comment: @MitjaBezenšek `[IgnoreDataMember]` says to not emit in the request body, but if it's referenced as part of the Route it will still get used, so it's a way to add it on the path only.

Comment: I now tried the first route from my original question but with [IgnoreDataMember] on the first two properties. I got an error:None of the given rest routes matches 'GetIssue' request:

 repositories/{AccountName}/{RepositorySlug}/issues/{local_id}: Variable 'AccountName' does not match any property.

Variable 'RepositorySlug' does not match any property.

Comment: @MitjaBezenšek are you using the latest v4 builds for this? If you're using v3 it's likely not implemented, if you're using v4 can you extend your question with the exact C# code used (so I can repro), the exception details and the expected output.

Comment: I have tested it a bit more and this seems to be a v3 related issue. I think I have narrowed it down the GetQueryProperties method of the UrlExtensions class. So the answer to my question is: it should work by using [IgnoreDataMember] but it is bugged in the v3 version. My solution of overriding the relativeUrl works so I guess I'll just stick to that until this is fixed. Here is the diff (check around line 25): http://www.diffchecker.com/u1nyqpcw